# How do I make a S or K letter in for loop java

Tags: java, for-loop

How do I make S letter or K in java? I have tried this but it makes ZL

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < n; column++) {
            if (row == 0 || row == n - 1 || column == n - 1 - row) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean ? just `System.out.println("S");` ?

Comment: Maybe he wants to print `K` using `*` as pixels...

Comment: @vincrichaud what a drag i wanna loop but i can't edit the post

Comment: @user6690200 u got it

Comment: Do top half and bottom half seperate and then put them together. Might help you to figure it out yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to display something like this (as suggested by user6690200) :

```
> //K with n=7
> *    *
> *   *
> *  *
> * *
> *  *
> *   *
> *    *
```

The easy case is only the K cause it is symetric, I don't think you can use a loop for S.

Here is the code that display the above K : (work only for n uneven)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    // Higher half of the K
    for (int row = 0; row < (n-1)/2; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < n-1; column++) {
            if (column == 0 || column == n-2-row ) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    //Middle line
    System.out.println("* *");
    // Lower half of the K
    for (int row = (n-1)/2-1; row >= 0; row--) {
        for (int column = 0; column < n-1; column++) {
            if (column == 0 || column == n-2-row ) {
                System.out.print("*");
            } else {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```